# Dynamic Templates for CKEditor

Tags: javascript, asp.net, templates, dynamic, ckeditor

I've got CKEditor embedded on a UserControl in our web application. All works fine with loading the default templates for CKEditor, on my local machine and our server.

I'm fetching templates from a database table, transforming the results to the appropriate JSON format and then writing that to a javascript file to add to CKEDITOR.template_files.

An example of the js content I'm generating in the js file:

```
CKEDITOR.addTemplates('templateskey',{imagesPath:'',templates:[{title:'LCH - Complaint', image:'', description:'Message Template - Complaints', html:'HtmlContent'}]});
```

Now my problem is that on our server my dynamically created js file seems to get blocked since it's supposed to load over HTTPS. Either this or my file can't be found.

> [blocked] The page at 'https://...' was loaded over HTTPS, but ran
>   insecure content from 'http://...' (page not found url): this content
>   should also be loaded over HTTPS.

After this CKEDITOR.config tries to load the "templatesKey" template and fails to do so with:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'imagesPath' of undefined

I've downloaded the ASP.Net version of CKEditor and included the project in my solution. I'm setting myCKEditor.TemplatesFiles and myCKEditor.Templates in the code behind:

```
myCKEditor.TemplatesFiles = "['" + relativePath + "']";
myCKEditor.Templates = "templateskey";
```

Is the problem that I'm generating the js file dynamically? Or is the problem that the templates plugin is loading content over HTTP rather than HTTPS? Is there a better way to dynamically add templates to CKEditor?

Comment: A possible solution with Ajax. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636696/ckeditor-template-loaded-from-ajax

Answer (score 0):

So talking to my friend that has expertise in SSH and HTTPS. This might be a limitation on HTTPS since I'm generating content dynamically it sees the content as a possible threat and unsecure.

[CkEditor - Template loaded from AJAX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12636696/ckeditor-template-loaded-from-ajax) is a good solution to the problem.

If you're working with ASP .Net you can build a Handler. Call the handler with ajax and pass JSON back.

e.g. The handler:

```
//Implement IRequiresSessionState is you want anything from the session state
public class TemplateHandler : IHttpHandler, IRequiresSessionState
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// You will need to configure this handler in the Web.config file of your 
        /// web and register it with IIS before being able to use it. For more information
        /// see the following link: http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=8101007
        /// </summary>
        #region IHttpHandler Members

        public bool IsReusable
        {
            // Return false in case your Managed Handler cannot be reused for another request.
            // Usually this would be false in case you have some state information preserved per request.
            get { return true; }
        }

        public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {
            try
            {
                //write your handler implementation here.
                string ID = Convert.ToString(context.Session["ID"]);

                DataSet dsTemplates = ExecuteStoredProc("uspTemplateRead");
                if (!dsTemplates.ContainsData())
                    return;

                List<Template> templates = new List<Template>();
                foreach (DataRow row in dsTemplates.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    Template template = new Template();
                    template.Title = row["Title"].ToString();
                    template.Image = "template.gif";
                    template.Description = row["Descr"].ToString();
                    template.Html = row["Temp"].ToString();
                    templates.Add(template);
                }

                byte[] b;
                DataContractJsonSerializer jsonSerializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Template>));
                using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    jsonSerializer.WriteObject(stream, templates);
                    b = stream.ToArray();
                }
                context.Response.Clear();
                context.Response.ContentType = "application/json";
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", b.Length.ToString());
                context.Response.BinaryWrite(b);
                context.Response.Flush();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
}
```

And then the Ajax call:

```
CKEDITOR.on("instanceReady", function () {
    try {
        var httpRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();

        httpRequest.onreadystatechange = function () {
            var json;
            if (this.responseText == "")
                json = "";
            else
                json = JSON.parse(this.responseText);

            var template = {
                imagesPath: CKEDITOR.getUrl(CKEDITOR.plugins.getPath("templates") + "templates/images/"),
                templates: json
            };
            CKEDITOR.addTemplates('myTemplates', template);
        };
        httpRequest.open('GET', '/handlers/templatehandler.ashx');
        httpRequest.send();
    } catch (ex) {
        console.log(ex);
    }

});
```